# TexMaker: Spellchecker adds & symbol, when choosing a suggested word

Tags: texmaker, spelling, dictionaries

In Texmaker, when I mistype a word, say "liok" and I choose a suggested word, like "look", it adds this symbol "&" at the beginning or in the middle of the word.

First, I thought, that the dictionary wasn't good. I changed the dictionary, but the problem remained.

Any suggestions? Please take a look at the gif.

[image]

EDIT: I realized, that the &-symbol gets added, where the underline in the selection is. Maybe this information helps you:

[image]

Comment: I would first check if you have the newest version of Texmaker, and if you don't, update. Beyond that I would contact the Texmaker maintainer about this.